# I want to return the number of top-level elements in a "duo" lists

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean

Trying to do a Boolean test loop where the user needs to enter a number between 10 and 1000 including 10 and 1000, they need to stay in this loop until they enter the correct number once they do then I will finish the else statement.

I tried this:

```
while (num_years < 10) and (num_years > 1000):  # boolean test , note ==  (= will give you an error!)
    print("Your input must be 10 and 1000")
    input("Enter number of years to simulate (currently " + str(num_years) + "): ")  
else:
    print()
```

AND this:

```
while (num_years == range(10, 1000)):  # boolean test , note ==  (= will give you an error!)
    print("Your input must be 10 and 1000")
    input("Enter number of years to simulate (currently " + str(num_years) + "): ")  
else:
    print()
```

Comment: OFFTOPIC comment: from which I recall you never mark your questions as answered, please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) link.

Comment: Tip *"Your input must be 10 and 1000"* does not make sense (a number cannot [be](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/be) two different numbers... Furthermore even if you add the word **between** at an appropriate position you should still clarify if you want **inclusive**, (10 are 1000 are allowed) or **exclusive**, (10 are 1000 are not allowed).  Finally I think the online course you are taking on python's author would appreciate it if you marked your python questions stemmed from their course as answered when most of them [are](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7443013/supernova) :)

Comment: between and including

Comment: here was my original question: Trying to do a Boolean test loop where the user needs to enter a number between 10 and 1000 including 10 and 1000,

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this as it also checks if the user inputs a valid number:

```
while True:
  number = input("Enter number of years to simulate (10-1000): ")
  try:
    years = int(number)
    if years >= 10 and years <= 1000: 
      break
    else:
      print("Your input must be between 10 and 1000 inclusive")
  except ValueError:
    print("That's not an int!")

print("Simulating %d years..." % years)
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter number of years to simulate (10-1000):  asd
That's not an int!
Enter number of years to simulate (10-1000):  5
Your input must be between 10 and 1000 inclusive
Enter number of years to simulate (10-1000):  245
Simulating 245 years...
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/Ffsl)

Comment: It seems to be best answer (not to the question perse but the comments). +1 one for you sir since I never would have guessed that this is what OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all:

```
(num_years < 10) and (num_years > 1000)
```

this is always False since one number cannot be less than 10 and more than 1000 at the same time.

Second of all

```
num_years == range(10, 1000)
```

will never work since you have (probably) integer on the left and [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) on the right.

However you might try something like that:

```
possible_years = range(10,101)
num_years = 50
while num_years in possible_years:  # or 9 < num_years < 100
    print("Your input must be 10 and 1000")
    entered_years = input("Enter number of years to simulate (currently " + str(num_years) + "): ")
    num_years = int(entered_years) # remeber to check if entered_years is int before this line!
else:
    print()
```

However there is still a catch, you need to check if user entered an integer.

Comment: it didnt work, I put in 10 and it went right thru the loop,

Comment: @Supernova because you excluded 10 from the range `num_years <10`. I edited my answer to suit your needs.

Comment: `list(range(...))` is not necessary `range()` supports `in` operator and is more memory efficient, e.g. `50 in range(10, 1001) == True`. Note: the range is `range(10, 1001)`:

Comment: @AChampion, that is very true. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: its still not validating if I enter 10 it is telling me to enter the range:

Comment: Welcome to the exponential growth model visualization
Enter number of years to simulate (currently 200): 10
Your input must be 10 and 1000

Answer (score 0):

You are never changing the value of `num_years` so the condition will never change. Fixing your boolean logic:

```
num_years = 0
while (num_years < 10) or (num_years > 1000):
    print("Your input must be 10 and 1000")
    num_years = int(input("Enter number of years to simulate (currently {}): ".format(num_years)))
else:
    print()
```

However, this assumes someone is entering a number if you need to cover a non-numeric value then use a `try: except: pass` block:

```
try:
    num_years = int(input("Enter number of years to simulate (currently {}): ".format(num_years)))
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Note: `=` is assignment not an equality test. Use `in` to test if a value is in a `list` or `range`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is a while loop to check whether the input is valid. If it's not, it will loop again. Also you never assign the input to a variable.

```
n = None
while n is None or not 10 <= n <= 1000:

    if n is not None: # Only happens if it's not the first input
        print('Invalid number, please try again')

    try:
        n = int( input('Enter number of years to simulate (10-1000): ') ) # Convert the
                                                                          # string to an int
    except:
        pass

print( 'Simulating {} years...'.format(n) )
```

It will continue and say simulating once a valid number is input because

```
not 10 <= n <= 1000
```

will evaluate to false.

You can try it at this link: https://repl.it/FftK/0

Comment: when I enter a number in range for example 15 it is still says enter a number between 10 and 1000

Comment: What python version are you on? I'm on 3.6 and it works as expected. Look at the repl link, it works there.

Comment: Almost have it it checks the fist time but not the second:

Comment: while num_years >= 10 and num_years <= 1000:  # boolean test , note ==  (= will give you an error!)
    print()
else:
    print("Your input must be 10 and 1000")
    input("Enter number of years to simulate (currently " + str(num_years) + "): ")  
print()

Comment: It works fine for me for as many iterations I do... Did you look at the repl link?

Comment: yes it works sorry for not replying sooner thank you

Comment: It's good. Anyway, if this is the answer you're using, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer please, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

n = None
while n is None or not 10 <= n <= 1000:

```
if n is not None: # Only happens if it's not the first input
    print('Invalid number, please try again')

try:
    n = int( input('Enter number of years to simulate (10-1000): ') ) # Convert the
                                                                      # string to an int
except:
    pass
```

print( 'Simulating {} years...'.format(n) )